# Using <input type="text"/> vertically aligns text?

Tags: html, css, forms, input

For some reason one of my inputs acts weird. I apply general css for all my inputs

```
.text-input {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    width: 330px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

and I apply this specific css for one particular div to make it higher

```
#letter {   
    height: 100px;
}
```

For some reason when I focus on #letter input and start typing text appears in vertical middle of it, I don't know what is causing the problem, but here is my page, if you focus on "Message" input you will see what I mean (tested in chrome).

http://freshbeer.lv/development/en/contact.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want to use a `textarea` instead? `input type="text"` is single line only.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Text Area element for that.

```
<textarea></textarea>
```